# Failed to mount /sysroot on my board

Tags: linux-kernel

I am working on an x86 based embedded board. I am able to load the kernel, 
    while loading initramfs filesystem, getting below error. Failed to mount /sysroot. 
    Here I am using a dracut initramfs filesystem of 3.10 to 3.14 kernel by renaming it. 
    Am I missing any Linux kernel changes.

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /sysroot.
See 'systemctl status sysroot.mount' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Initrd Root File System.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Reload Configuration from the Real Root.
random: nonblocking pool is initialized
systemd[1]: Starting Emergency Shell...
systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
systemd-journald[130]: Received SIGTERM
systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It *seems* that your kernel is missing intrd support. Have you checked the `.config` file (or, alternatively, checked through `make menuconfig`) to see if the kernel supports initrd ?

Comment: Hi Claudio, Problem resolved, my intrd is mouted on /dev/sd3, which is using xfs filesystem. I have not enabled XFS Filesytem. Once Enabled it is working.